# NPE in Fragment when setting textView

Tags: java, android

I Have host `MainActivity` and 2 Fragments: `MainFragment` and `StringsFragment`.

I want to set text in TextView (which is in `MainFragment`) from `StringsFragment`.

So in `StringsFragment` I have:

```
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    void messengeFromBroadcastFragment(String value);
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    String myValue = "helloWorld";
    mListener.messengeFromBroadcastFragment(myValue);
}
```

In MainFragment:

```
TextView tv;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        tv = view.findViewById(R.id.tv);
        return view;
    }

    public void setTextView(String value){
        tv.setText(value);
    }
```

and MainActivity:

```
public void messengeFromBroadcastFragment(String value) {
    mainFragment = new MainFragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, mainFragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
    mainFragment.setTextView(value);
}
```

And when I call onClick from StringsFragment, I got nullpointer:

```
setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

from here

```
public void setTextView(String value){
    tv.setText(value);
}
```

Comment: `tv` is `null`. Use the debugger to find out why. If you still need help, please [edit] your question to show a [mcve]. Every method should be inside a class.

Comment: `FragmentTransaction`s execute asynchronously, by default. That `Fragment` has not yet created its `View` by the time you're calling `mainFragment.setTextView(value)`.

Comment: is null because tv.setText is run before onCreateView, but how to fix this ?

Comment: If you really want to set it right there, call `getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();` right after the `commit()`. Or, if you're using at least version 26.1.0 of the support library, you can just use `commitNow()`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like when you call

```
mainFragment.setTextView(value);
```

Your tv `TextView` is not exists yet.

For fixing it you have to use `Bundle` for passing `String` from `Activity` to fragment.

Also there are another variants like:

1. Storing values in `Singleton`
2. Storing values in `Shared Preferences`
3. Creating queue of values you should display with `Observer` pattern
4. Using `ReplayRelay` from [RxRelay](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxRelay) library as `RxBus` . Actually
   almost the same as 3rd option

So there will be a bit less boilerplate than using `Bundle`

Comment: hey, it's answer for how to deliver value to fragment, but my problem is set the tv after initialize

Comment: @goodweather its answer how to solve your problem correctly. For sure you can do something like calling setText after 1 second delay for example and in most cases it will work